# Android build system gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-build

I am testing androids new build system which still is in beta.
I have implemented some code which generates following error:

```
No such property: resolutionResult for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.2'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
  sourceSets {
      main {
          manifest {
              srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
          }
          java {
              srcDir 'src'
          }
          res {
              srcDir 'res'
          }
          assets {
              srcDir 'assets'
          }
          resources {
              srcDir 'src'
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I have tried samples too, which raises the same error. What's wrong?

Gradle Version

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Dienstag, 20. November 2012 11:37 Uhr UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.6.0_25 (Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.0-b11)
OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Full Gradle Stacktrace

```
org.gradle.listener.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:97)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at $Proxy9.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:47)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:463)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:75)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:23)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:21)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$CompositeAction.execute(Actions.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$TransformingActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:96)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:439)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:434)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:137)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: resolutionResult for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.resolveDependencyForConfig(BasePlugin.groovy:641)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$resolveDependencyForConfig.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.resolveDependencies(BasePlugin.groovy:584)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$resolveDependencies.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.createAndroidTasks(AppPlugin.groovy:116)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.this$3$createAndroidTasks(AppPlugin.groovy)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin$_apply_closure5.doCall(AppPlugin.groovy:73)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ClosureInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:116)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ClosureInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:101)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:88)
        ... 33 more
```

I've tried downgrading to Gradle 1.2. Now i get another exception.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Mittwoch, 12. September 2012 10:46 Uhr UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.6.0_25 (Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.0-b11)
OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Stacktrace after downgrading to Gradle 1.2

```
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseAidl'.
> target cannot be null.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseAidl'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$3.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:243)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:188)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:241)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:137)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:247)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:30)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$2.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:118)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:133)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:116)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:129)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ActionAdapter.execute(ActionAdapter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ActionAdapter.execute(ActionAdapter.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:200)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:173)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:138)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: target cannot be null.
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:208)
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder.setTarget(AndroidBuilder.java:131)
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder$setTarget.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ProductionAppVariant.createBuilder(ProductionAppVariant.groovy:90)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ProductionAppVariant$createBuilder.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.getAndroidBuilder(BasePlugin.groovy:133)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$getAndroidBuilder.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BaseTask.getBuilder(BaseTask.groovy:33)
        at com.android.build.gradle.CompileAidlTask_Decorated.getBuilder(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.CompileAidlTask_Decorated$getBuilder.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.CompileAidlTask.generate(CompileAidlTask.groovy:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:122)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
        at com.android.build.gradle.CompileAidlTask_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:161)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:156)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:472)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:461)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:60)
        ... 58 more
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? My hunch is you're running it against the wrong version of Gradle (perhaps an earlier or preview build?) This is an internal error raised during configuration resolution, so perhaps the Android plugin is trying to access a Gradle property which doesn't exist in your installation of Gradle. What does `gradle -v` say?

Comment: Added full stacktrace and gradle version in answer.

Comment: The Android plugin is built for Gradle 1.2. Try downgrading your Gradle installation and see if that helps.

Comment: I went a few steps further, but when building the app another exception raises. See more in edited post

Comment: You have to set the `target` attribute to whichever platform version you're targeting with your app. Have you followed http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/using-the-new-build-system ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 0.2 was developed with Gradle 1.2 (1.3 wasn't out yet). We know we are using some internal stuff for now, so it's possible it's broken on 1.3 (haven't tested yet, will do it soon).

For now, please use Gradle 1.2

Comment: quick update, we fixed the issue, so the next update will be usable with 1.3 (actually, it will require 1.3 and we've put checks to ensure the right version is used).

Comment: Gradle 1.4 is already out.. I wish that Gradle plugins weren't so broken every new gradle release. Maven is waaay more stable for now.

Comment: This was our fault really. We were using an incubating feature. The next version will work on 1.3/1.4 (we're testing on both)

Comment: Looks like .3, which supports 1.3/1.4 is available (with unknown stability) in the AOSP tools checkout. See 'Contributing' at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Comment: 0.3 is still under development and requires a version of platform--tools that has not be released yet.

Comment: additional notes besides: regardless on an installed gradle version, you could add the gradle wrapper to the project and bind the wrapper to gradle version 1.2. Like this, you can ensure that every developer uses the same gradle version without messing around with multiple gradle installations. This should work for CI, too.

Comment: @Xav I'm experiencing this issue with 0.3 & 1.3, complains target must not be null... Will post SO question later..

Comment: target was renamed compileSdkVersion. Make sure to read the new doc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `compliedSdkVersion 17` to your gradle.build file:

**Edit**: reference project I just created. Builds, signs,etc https://github.com/yegdroid/gradle_demo

```
//
// A basic Android application that follows all the conventions
//
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    testBuildType = "debug"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "0.1"
        minSdkVersion = 9
        targetSdkVersion = 17


        compileSdkVersion 17
        buildConfig "private final static boolean DEFAULT = true;", \
                    "private final static String FOO = \"foo\";"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix = ".debug"

            buildConfig "private final static boolean DEBUG2 = false;"
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "txt"
    }
    sourceSets {
          main {
              manifest {
                  srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
              }
              java {
                  srcDir 'src'
              }
              res {
                  srcDir 'res'
              }
              assets {
                  srcDir 'assets'
              }
              resources {
                  srcDir 'src'
              }
          }
      }
}
```